# libpcre unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I have exhausted all things that I found online trying to fix following on ubuntu 22.04

```
#apt install libpcre2-dev
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (= 10.39-3ubuntu0.1) but 10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpcre2-16-0 (= 10.39-3ubuntu0.1) but 10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpcre2-32-0 (= 10.39-3ubuntu0.1) but 10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Apparently problem is due to dist-upgrade issue from 21.10.

What I have tried so far:

```
apt upgrade
apt install -f libpcre2-dev
apt autoclean
apt --fix-broken install
```

Also here's the output of

```
apt-cache policy libpcre2-8-0
libpcre2-8-0:
  Installed: 10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.39-3ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     10.39-3build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Which I am not sure how to use...?

Comment: Do you have the "universe" repository enabled? Did you add some 3rd party source (PPA)?

Comment: Stupid me for asking stupid questions ^^^ (at least one of them). OF COURSE you added a 3rd party source from https://deb.sury.org/ and the wrong one by the look of it (Debian DPA)...

Comment: @ChanganAuto ok so what do I do to remove that wrong one? Remove it from where and add which one?

Comment: Remove it the same way you added it or at Software & Updates > other... You don't need to add any 3rd party repository but if you think you need then make sure to add the "Ubuntu PPA" mentioned in the website above.

Comment: I have installed it, but still: https://gist.github.com/acosonic/bdfafd54189c7a4f0e319a2338324e90

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I was able to resolve this issue the following way:

1. Installed apptitude `sudo apt install aptitude`
2. Then `aptitude install libpcre2-dev`
3. Do not accept default option to keep existing, choose N
4. Accept solution to downgrade

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
     Downgrade the following packages:                                                                                    
1)     libpcre2-16-0 [10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 10.39-3ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]     
2)     libpcre2-16-0:i386 [10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 10.39-3ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
3)     libpcre2-32-0 [10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 10.39-3ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]     
4)     libpcre2-8-0 [10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 10.39-3ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]      
5)     libpcre2-8-0:i386 [10.40-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 10.39-3ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)] 



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me on wsl too. :)